# Android OS 6 Marshallow Cannot Run version 4.0.3 app on Camera?

Tags: android

When I build the project, I select android 4.0.3 IceCreamSandwich. After that I install at both android os.6 and android os.4 phone. I realize that only work for operating system 4, newer API cannot support older API ?? It sound not logic.........

Andoird manifast

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jackd.testflash_26_4_2017">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Android Main

```
package com.example.jackd.testflash_26_4_2017;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Camera camera;
    private Camera.Parameters params;
    Button btnFlash;
    TextView txtArea,txtArea2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnFlash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);

        final String myString = "110101010101";
        final long blinkDelay = 50;



    btnFlash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i = 0;i<myString.length();i++){

                if(myString.charAt(i) == '0'){

                   params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }
                else{
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                }
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (isFlashSupported()) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        params = camera.getParameters();
    } else {
        showNoFlashAlert();
    }
}


private void showNoFlashAlert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Your device hardware does not support flashlight!")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Error")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }).show();
}
private boolean isFlashSupported() {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(camera != null){
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Android XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.jackd.testflash_26_4_2017.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

PS: I have open all the permission for camera hardware. In OS6, it need to open manually, I had done that !

Back to the question, does the Version6 Marshmallow android cannot support version4 iceCreamSandwith? But, logically higher version should support lower version .... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

android developer :

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

you can check this for more info:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html